# Get private key out of a .pfx file in c#

Tags: c#, certificate, private-key, pfx

I am needing the private key of a key-pair generated for digital signature using EC algorithm. I need it in `byte[]` to sign data inside a specific method in C++ that only accepts `byte[]` format. 
The private key is contained in a `.pfx` file that has both, public and private. 
Despite that, I am not able to extract the `byte[]` out of the file.

```cs
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(fileName, password);
ECDsa privateKey = certificate.GetECDsaPrivateKey();
// TODO: how to extract byte[] from privateKey?
```

Is there a way of doing it or is it impossible and the private key should be stored elsewhere and not in a `.pfx` file?

Comment: ECPrivateKey, PKCS#8 PrivateKeyInfo, or PKCS#8 EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo?  .NET Framework or .NET Core? What versions are available to you?  Windows, non-Windows, or both?

Comment: It is a .net standard 2.0 library. It is intended for Windows. I look for the 16 bytes of the private key stored either in a PKCS#8 file or PKCS #12 (I have both files available)